# IIS 7 UNC Virtual Directory tests ok, but gives 404 when browsed

Tags: iis, unc

I've created a virtual directory using IIS 7 on Server 2008 that is a UNC path (\192.168.100.4\c...) to another server.  The file permissions on that server are set to Everyone, full control.  I've gone to Basic Settings, Connect As and set the credentials to ComputerName\Administrator of the remote server.  When I click [Test Settings] both Authentication and Authorization are green and says specified user credentials are valid.  When I click Content View in IIS, I see the folders and files.  I also enabled Directory Browsing.

On the local computer, I can browse the files using the url to the virtual directory.  However, when I go to any other computer and enter the same url or try to access a file, I get a 404 error.  What am I doing wrong?.. missed?

Comment: Can you share the IIS log for this error please?

Comment: There is no error in the event log and this is the only entry in the IIS Log:  2016-11-25 11:51:19 192.168.100.10 GET /CA/2821 - 80 - 76.242.102.xxx Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.2;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/54.0.2840.99+Safari/537.36 404 0 2 468

Comment: Sorry, tried again and got: 2016-11-25 12:44:02 192.168.100.10 GET /CA/2821/MOB_269_0_5.flv - 443 - 76.242.102.xxx Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.2;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/54.0.2840.99+Safari/537.36 404 0 2 46
2016-11-25 12:44:10 192.168.100.10 GET /CA/2821 - 80 - 76.242.102.xxx Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.2;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/54.0.2840.99+Safari/537.36 404 0 2 62

Comment: Certainly does look like a genuine 404 on the file GET /CA/2821/MOB_269_0_5.flv - is this file available on 192.168.100.4 folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the virtual directory and re-created it without it being an application and attached to a specific application pool.  Now, I'm able to access the files as I should.  I'm guessing that I had the wrong credentials in the application pool for that resource.